# Corda Unit Tests fail from missing @Suspendable

Tags: corda

When running unit tests on Corda Enterprise 4.1 previously working flow unit tests are crashing with the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Transaction context is missing. This might happen if a suspendable method is not annotated with @Suspendable annotation.
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.checkDbTransaction(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:233) ~[corda-node-4.1.20190823.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.processEventImmediately(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:224) ~[corda-node-4.1.20190823.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:294) ~[corda-node-4.1.20190823.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:45) ~[corda-node-4.1.20190823.jar:?]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91) ~[quasar-core-0.7.10-jdk8.jar:0.7.10]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_212]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:63) ~[corda-node-4.1.20190823.jar:?]
```

All methods correctly contains the `@Suspendable` annotation. What is causing the flow tests to fail?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the correct version of Quasar is being included in your Cordapp. The version has changed with Corda 4, check documentation for the required version of Quasar: https://docs.corda.r3.com/app-upgrade-notes-enterprise.html#re-compiling-for-release

For Corda 4.1 specifically this will be `ext.quasar_version = '0.7.11_r3'`.